# Is it possible to create plugin for mlflow custom model flavor?

Tags: python-3.x, mlflow

I have recently been using mlflow model registry, and was wondering if we could create plugin for mlflow flavor that is not supported.

I have tried adding custom flavor to the code and been able to successfully register models, just wanted to check if it's possible to create plugin instead of making code changes.